# How to solve problem with reading a shapefile in R

Tags: r, shapefile, rgdal

How do I show a map that is in shapefile format that is in a zip file. The file is this:

https://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2015/UFs/PR/pr_municipios.zip

I tried to do the following:

```
library(rgdal)

temp <- tempfile()
download.file("https://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2015/UFs/PR/pr_municipios.zip",temp)
data <- readOGR(unz(temp, "41MUE250GC_SIR.shp"))
```

But it did not work.

The map will look like the one below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(rgdal)

temp <- tempfile()
temp2 <- tempfile()
download.file("https://geoftp.ibge.gov.br/organizacao_do_territorio/malhas_territoriais/malhas_municipais/municipio_2015/UFs/PR/pr_municipios.zip",temp)

unzip(zipfile = temp, exdir = temp2)
shp <- readOGR(temp2)

plot(shp)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply friend! Can you tell me if there is a way to increase the map line? to make it more prominent?

Comment: Use ggplot package.... See the documentation for geom_polygon()... You can change almost every atribute style